# Noise a Hoctaedron Sphere in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector

Now I have an octahedron sphere  and I woud like to add noise to it, but I can' t do it because I dont know to much of this,
I think I need to modify the vertex pos but i don't know how.
Here is the script that generate the vertices, If you need More, only Ask (;

```
Vector3[] vertices = new Vector3[(resolution + 1) * (resolution + 1) * 4 - (resolution * 2 - 1) * 3];

int v = 0, vBottom = 0, t = 0;
        
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
{
    vertices[v++] = Vector3.down;
}

for (int i = 1; i <= resolution; i++) 
{
    float progress = (float)i / resolution;
    Vector3 from, to;
    vertices[v++] = to = Vector3.Lerp(Vector3.down, Vector3.up, progress);
    for (int d = 0; d < 4; d++) 
    {
        from = to;
        to = Vector3.Lerp(Vector3.down, directions[d], progress);
        t = CreateLowerStrip(i, v, vBottom, t, triangles);
        v = CreateVertexLine(from, to, i, v, vertices);
        vBottom += i > 1 ? (i - 1) : 1;
    }
    vBottom = v - 1 - i * 4;
}
```

Comment: what exactly do you mean by noise? Couldn't you just iterate through all verts and move them around by random vectors within a certain range?

Comment: I do not know how to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how exactly your noise should look like the simplest I can imagine would be to simply iterate through the vertices and slightly shift them around by random direction vectors with a random magnitude up to a certain maximum like e.g.

```
void Randomize(Vector3[] vertices, float maxDistance)
{
    for(var i = 0; i< vertices.Length; i++)
    {
        // Generates a random vactor pointing in any possible direction
        var randomDirection = new Vector3(Random.Range(-1f, 1f), Random.Range(-1f, 1f), Random.Range(-1f, 1f)).normalized;
        // Generate a random magnitude between 0 and given maxDistance
        var randomMagnitude = Random.Range(0, maxDistance);

        // Move the current vert the randomMagnitude along the randomDirection  
        vertices[i] += randomDirection  * randomMagnitude;
    } 
}
```

---

Or alternatively you could only move on Vectors between the current vert position and the center (assuming `Vector3.zero` for now)

```
void RandomizeFromCenter(Vector3[] vertices, float maxDistance)
{
    var center = Vector3.zero;

    for(var i = 0; i< vertices.Length; i++)
    {
        var direction = (vertices[i] - center).normalized;

        // Generate a random magnitude between -maxDistance and maxDistance
        var randomMagnitude = Random.Range(-maxDistance, maxDistance);

        // Move the current vert the randomMagnitude along the randomDirection  
        vertices[i] += direction * randomMagnitude;
    } 
}
```